# Scrape just the text, within an html element that has a class, using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page using BeatifulSoup

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www.xpn.org/playlists/xpn-playlist'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    print link
```

The problem is the text I would like to return is not enclosed in it's own html tag

```
<li class="song"> <a href="/default.htm" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()
" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu1, 
'100px','Death Vessel','Mandan Dink','Stay Close')">Buy</a>  
Chuck Ragan - Rotterdam - Folkadelphia Session</li>
```

What I want to return
`Chuck Ragan - Rotterdam - Folkadelphia Session`

Bonus Points: The data returned is of the format Artist/Song/Album.  What would be the proper data structure to use to store and manipulate this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    print link.text
```

Output:

```
Buy  Chuck Ragan - Rotterdam - Folkadelphia Session
```

Sure, if you want to remove `Buy`, you can use `slice` like this:

```
for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    print link.text.strip()[5:]
```

The output is:

```
Chuck Ragan - Rotterdam - Folkadelphia Session
```

---

If you'd like save these string in a list:

```
[i.strip() for i in link.text.strip()[5:].split('-')]
```

Output:

```
['Chuck Ragan', 'Rotterdam', 'Folkadelphia Session']
```

---

For more info, you can check the  [document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: That's remove the first 5 characters. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: And about *What would be the proper data structure to use to store and manipulate this info?*, maybe use database?

Comment: Thinking more along the lines of dictionaries, sets, maps and the like.  I'm just not sure how to store something with three values.  In other words I would use a dict if it was just a key : value pair and I'm wondering if there is an analogue for three values.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks for the really complete answer.

Comment: @MichaelJames Hmm...I think that use database here is a good idea, that will be more simpler. `sqlite3` is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way! (assuming `li` has 3 children. If not, change `[2]` to `[1]`):

```
>>> html = '''<li class="song"> <a href="/default.htm" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()
... " onmouseout="delayhidemenu()" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu1,
... '100px','Death Vessel','Mandan Dink','Stay Close')">Buy</a>
... Chuck Ragan - Rotterdam - Folkadelphia Session</li>'''

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> all_li = soup.findAll('li', class_='song')
>>> for li in all_li:
...     text = list(li.children)[2]
...     artist, song, album = text.split('-')
...     print artist, song, album
Chuck Ragan   Rotterdam   Folkadelphia Session
```

Comment: Tried this solution but got an error `----> 9 all_li = soup.findall('li', class_='song')` `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: Notice that `soup.findAll()` and `soup.findall()` are different functions! The one we are looking for is `soup.findAll()` not the one you tried :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
for l in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    album = l.text.split("-")[2]
    song = l.text.split("-")[1]
    artist = l.text.split("-")[0].split(" ")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**   Ended up using a `named tuple` for storage  **

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from collections import namedtuple

url='http://www.xpn.org/playlists/xpn-playlist'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

songs=[]
Song = namedtuple("Song", "artist name album")
for link in soup.find_all("li", class_="song"):
    song = Song._make(link.text.strip()[12:].split(" - "))
    songs.append(song)

for song in songs:
    print(song.artist, song.name, song.album)
```